# Hyper-links in Jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a Javascript function to add values to my Jquery datatable.

```
var table2 = document.getElementById('tstable2');

                    for (i = 0; i < returnedData.length; i++){
                     $('#tstable2').dataTable().fnAddData([
                            returnedData[i].id,
                            returnedData[i].name,
                            returnedData[i].month,
                            returnedData[i].total_dur
                        ]);
```

I want to make the first column, ie returnedData[i].id as a hyperlink in the table which opens in a new tab. How can i add hyperlinks to my Jquery Data-table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
var table2 = document.getElementById('tstable2');

                    for (i = 0; i < returnedData.length; i++){
                     $('#tstable2').dataTable().fnAddData([
                            '[<a href="http://yourUrlhere" target="_blank"">'+returnedData[i].id+'</a>]',
                            returnedData[i].name,
                            returnedData[i].month,
                            returnedData[i].total_dur
                        ]);
```